# Access tabular report Can Grow wrapping text - I need expanding

Tags: ms-access, report

I have an Access 2010 report that I've setup as tabular and set 2 columns with Can Grow and Can Shrink to Yes but instead of expanding the width it's instead wrapping the text.  Is it possible to have it expand the width of the column instead of wrapping the text and expanding it's height?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Can Grow`/`Can Shrink` are what you expect them to be. These properties only concern fitting controls to a page when printing. I suspect you want to edit the `Horizontal Anchor` property. You can set this to `Left`, `Right`, or `Both`.

What this will do is, say when set to `Left`, is bind the control to the left hand side of the Form/Report while leaving width constant.

When `Right` is set the control will move with the right side of the form/report and stay the same width.

When `Both` is set the control's width will change to maintain the same distance of the left side of the control to the left side of the form/report and same for the right side.